# GET request in Flask - send data from python backend to client

Tags: javascript, flask, get

I have a page that asks the user for informations, the user selects options and confirms his choice. The answers are sent to the backend, and a file is made.
I want to send back the file to the user but for this I have to send information from the backend to the frontend.

I tried using "return render_template" and "redirect" but it didn't work

I have been told I have to do a GET request but I'm not sure how to do this, I know how to send data from client to server but I never did from server to client and I haven't found how to do this with Flask.

```
@app.route('/createdocument', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
#@login_required
def create_document():
    playlists = get_playlists()
    if request.method == "POST":
        request_data = str(request.data.decode('UTF-8'))
        genre = get_header_genre(request_data)
        parsed_data = parse_request(request_data)           
        playlist_names = get_parsed_playlists(parsed_data)
        if genre == "playlist":
            #make_playlist_doc(playlist_names, genre)
            print("playlist option not ready yet")
        elif genre == "socan":
            name = make_socan_doc(playlist_names, genre)
            return render_template("tools/downloadfile.html", document=name)
        else:
            print("other request:")
            print(str(request.data.decode('UTF-8')))
    if request.method == "GET":
        ########################## Something I guess but I don't know what
   return render_template("tools/createdocument.html", playlists=playlists)
```

I found this looking for a GET request

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

If I understand well I should but `/createdocument` in theUrl, but what should I put in callback ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with the return render_template approach. What exactly isn't working?

For the client - can you use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead; those are fairly common libraries these days to get GET requests from the client.

```
axios.get('/createdocument', {
    params: {}
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

That said if you are trying to do all of this asynchronously (i.e. the user submits the POST request and the file is not returned as part of that request, but is returned at some arbitrary later time), look into something like setting up a [web socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

Here is a [Flask-based websocket server that should work](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried return render_template() and redirect but it doesn't work (nothing happens).
I already asked about that issue: shorturl.at/gwB14
I understand it a little better what's expected by flask but I still don't have a solution.
Ideally render_template would work but if I can't find a way to send back data from the server to the front I'll have to avoid that, I can find a way around but I'll run again into that problem pretty soon and it's a terrible design constraint :(